# Snowflake spatial data not working in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*I have tried to create a map visual in ssrs with snowflake spatial data , But the visual not recognising the data as spatial.

*I have couple of doubt, Can we create map report in SSRS by using snowflake spatial data?

*Why ssrs map visual is not recognize snowflake Spatial data as spatial.

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example of the spatial data (the table DDL and sample data) and an example of what you are trying to do in SSRS?

Comment: The snow flake spatial data type is geometry, the format in the column is in geojson, I'm trying to create map, but the ssrs map visual is not recognise it as spatial column.